# Math.random and mixture of letters abcd etc

Tags: javascript, random

I'm generating a random number with the code below:

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999) * 7);
```

Some of the results I'm getting:

```
45130,
2611,
34509,
36658
```

How would I get results like this(with 2 letters included):

```
TT45130,
PO2611,
KL34509,
GH36658
```

Side question:

What is the range of numbers that `Math.random()` carries? Can I set a specific range of values? Not necessary to answer but just curious.

Comment: Math.random() returns values between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). If you want other numbers, you have to make them yourself, like you are already doing

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but I'm unsure what the best/correct answer is now... Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a function like below to get a random uppercase character:

```
function getRandomUppercaseChar() {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
    return String.fromCharCode(65 + r);
}
```

So to generate a code as you specified with a two-letter prefix:

```
function generateCode() {
    var prefix = new Array(2).fill().map(() => getRandomUppercaseChar()).join(""),
        integer = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999) * 7);
    return prefix + integer;
}
```

**NOTE:** The above `generateCode` function uses modern ES6 and ES5 javascript, which is perfectly fine in a modern environment (such as Node.js or a current browser). However, if you wanted greater compatibility (for example, to ensure that it works in old browsers), you could rewrite it like so:

```
function generateCode() {
    var integer = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999) * 7);
    for (var i = 0, prefix = ""; i < 2; ++i)
        prefix += getRandomUppercaseChar();
    return prefix + integer;
}
```

Comment: This would only generate upperclass chars from A to Y, as Math.random() can never be 1. It should be var r = Math.round(Math.random() * 26); to also include the possibility of a Z.

Comment: `Math.random()` can never be 1. But it *can* be rounded up to 1, so it works. You can test it like this if you want: `for (var i = 0; i < 1e3; i++) { if (Math.round(Math.random() * 25) === 25) console.log("equals 25"); }`

Comment: Don't use Math.round() for this. It skews the probabilities. Math.floor() gives an equal probability for all numbers

Comment: You should always use `floor()` instead of `round()` to ensure equal probability of all outcomes. So multiplying by is 26 right

Comment: Okay, thanks for that, I'll change my answer to use `floor`.

Comment: You are right, user162097. My suggestion to use Math.round(Math.random() * 26) was wrong and would yield results such as "[". Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) would be more correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try the simpler answer

```
var randomNumber = function () {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999) * 7);
}
var randomChar = function () {
    return String.fromCharCode(64 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 26)+1));
}
console.log(randomChar()+randomChar()+randomNumber());
//Sample outputs
HB10527 DR25496 IJ12394
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use [`Number#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) for this purpose with `radix = 36`.

```js
function getRChar() {
    return (Math.random() * 26 + 10 | 0).toString(36).toUpperCase();
}

var s = getRChar() + getRChar() + Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999) * 7);

document.write(s);
```

Comment: That's a clever way of doing it!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to generate a random string with JS, the most common way is to define an alphabet and pick random indices from that:

```
var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var numbers = "0123456789";

var randomString = "";

// Pick two random chars
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*alphabet.length);
  randomString = randomString + alphabet.charAt(rand);
}

// Pick four random digits
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*numbers.length);
  randomString = randomString + numbers.charAt(rand);
}

// randomString now contains the string you want
```

Sample strings:

```
OJ8225
YL5053
BD7911
ES0159
```

Comment: why use loops for the numbers? at least in my version - it was a single calculation not a loop thats iterated four times with a calculation in each round. Doesn't seem very efficient to me... and you could have simplified the code even more as follows ...randomString += numbers.charAt(rand);... not very efficient or practical.... see what I did there... we should be supporting each other not breaking down tiny flaws in each others code.

Comment: More flexible. Also, this will always generate a string of 2 chars and 4 digits. If you just floor a random number between 0 and 10000, you could end up with any number of digits

Comment: fair pojnt - but I would say in my defence that the number part was from the OP, my part was the alphabet portion, which you didn't like. But you still could have done... randomString += alphabet.charAt(rand);... so my point still holds. Everyones code has potential to improve. Being negative with other posters serves no one

Comment: If I was too add this too my google analytics tracking code, would I use the var randomString to store the random number?

Answer (score 1):

An array of the alphabet, a random number is generated to get a random letter, repeated to get a second random letter and then joined to the random number generated as in your code:

```
var alphabet=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];

var ranletter1 = alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
var ranletter2 = alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
var ranNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999) * 7);

var ranCode = ranletter1 + ranletter2+ ranNum;
```

Comment: Not very maintainable nor easy-to-read code. And why not just ask the alphabet for its length, instead of hard-coding 26?

Comment: thanks - actually it only have 26 - had two "G" and no "H"... but all fixed now and whats hard to read - an array of letters and 3 instances of Math random!

Comment: The array of letters is unneccesarily complicated to write. Why not just a string?

Comment: @Suppen - different ways to the same end ['R','E','S','U','L','T'] and alphabet.length is a lot more characters than to code than 26... and unless I am mistaken is unlikely to change in length so why bother querying a known quantity

Comment: In this case, not very important. In larger programs, however, literals with no explanation or comments become very confusing. Also, why can't it change? What if the asker decides O and 0 looks too similar, and doesn't want the code to generate O? That requires three edits: One to remove it from the array, and two to edit the two 26es. What if 26 appears other places in the code? Easy to forget to change that, or easy to change a 26 that wasn't referring to the alphabet length. Search-and-replace is just too convenient

Comment: @Suppen so amended to alphabet.length

Answer (score 1):

You could use String.fromCharCode() with a random integer between 65 and 90 to get an uppercase letter, i.e.

```
String.fromCharCode(Math.random() * 26 + 65) + String.fromCharCode(Math.random() * 26 + 65) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999) * 7);
```

gives med the results: "SH21248", "BY42401", "TD35918".
If you want to guarantee that the string always has the same length, you could also use

```
String.fromCharCode(Math.random() * 26 + 65) + String.fromCharCode(Math.random() * 26 + 65) + Math.floor(Math.random() * 59993 + 10000);
```

Math.random() always returns a number between 0 and 1, but never 0 or 1 exactly.